# How to strip Oracle error code from the error message in Java?

Tags: java, oracle

How to get rid of Oracle error codes at the beginning of all custom Oracle error messages caught in Java?

```
String r = errorMessage.replaceFirst("^ORA-\\d+:?\\s?", "");
```

Is there a better way?

Oracle also adds some garbage to my pretty error message so it is followed by

```
ORA-06512: at "MY_SERVER.PKG_TEST", line 470
ORA-06512: at "MY_SERVER.PKG_TEST", line 406
ORA-06512: at "MY_SERVER.PKG_TEST", line 611
ORA-06512: at "MY_SERVER.PKG_TEST", line 643
```

Comment: Oracle error codes are extremely useful for researching why an error occurred. Why would you want to remove them?

Comment: If Java is just a wrapper for PL/SQL code then I want to pass exception messages transparently.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA` errors are always `ORA + 5 digits`, e.g.

```
SQL> select 1
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = (select deptno from dept);
where deptno = (select deptno from dept)
                *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


SQL>
```

`ORA-01427` is one of those. It means that - if you know *how* (I don't, as I don't speak Java), remove the first 9 characters (or 11, to remove `:` and a space) and that would be it. For example, using `substr` in Oracle:

```
SQL> select substr('ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row', 12) result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------
single-row subquery returns more than one row

SQL>
```

In other words, no need for *complex* regular expressions.

Comment: Java sqlException.getMessage() returns additional garbage like a bunch of ORA-06512 errors describing a stacktrace. I do not need it though.

Answer (score -1):

I think similar to `SUBSTR` in Oracle you could use `substring` in Java:

```
public class Simple{
public static void main(String args[]){
  String r = "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row";
  System.out.println(r.substring(11));
}}
```

Output:

```
single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

In Oracle, the start position of the substring is always `1`, but it's `0` in Java. So, in Oracle the query would be:

```
SUBSTR('ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row', 12)
```

Comment: It would be too easy to use a single substring() but now I see a lot of garbage ORA-06512 errors describing a PL/SQL stacktrace.